# Fix title to top when section is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to create an effect than when my user scrolls, my `h1` sticks to the top of the window. When the parent div has scrolled past the h1 is then 'released' and scrolls again as normal. When my next `section` comes in I'd then like to stick that next `h1` to the top again and so on.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Vk9G/1/)

*jQuery*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $('section h1').addClass('fixed');
    })
})
```

I've also tried :

```
var section = $('section');
distance = section.offset().top,
$window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
       section.find('h1').addClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is when to add and remove the fixed class?

Comment: That is one, and detecting when the next `section` comes into view to then apply the effect to that

Comment: your fiddle is working fine, what you want extra?

Comment: It's not @PratikJoshi, If you remove my javascript you will see more than 1 h1 tag, when you scroll they all overlay each other.

Comment: then what should happen ?

Comment: Its simple @PratikJoshi, if you take alook at this jsfiddle.net/kennis/JTvFZ you will see the letters stick to the top of the window until the next section pushes them off. I want a similar effect for my h1 tags, at the minute however all 5 of my h1 tags overlap each other

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do this using a bit of jQuery.

The following snippet calculates the offset of each section to the top of the window. When a section hits the top of the window, it's title `<h1>` position is changed to `position:fixed;`.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/spnSZ/)

*jQuery:*

```
function fixTitle() {
    $('section.affix').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var offset = $this.offset().top-40;
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop > offset) {
            $this.addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $this.removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(fixTitle);
});
```

*CSS:*

```
section {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0 20%;
    position:relative;
  text-align:justify;
}
section h1 {
    float:left;
    width:14%;
  padding-left:1.5%;
  line-height:40px;
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
section .summary {
    float:right;
    width:70%;
}
.fixed h1:first-child {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
h1:first-child:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  width:5%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#4381B6;
  z-index:-1;


}
.fixed h1:first-child:before{
  width:100%;
  -webkit-transition:width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: @Liam glad I could help. I am still working on the function as it can be improved (for a performance point of view.)

Comment: @Liam edited my answer. The function is much better now, I recommend you use this instead of the first one I posted.

Comment: @web-tiki Is there a reason that `$window` is defined globally without `var`? Ideally based on your code `$window` should be defined inside the `$(document).ready` callback.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this with CSS3 in some of the most recent browsers by using

```
.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: -o-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 15px;
}
```

See [this demo](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/sticky.html) (or [this demo with a polyfill](http://filamentgroup.github.io/fixed-sticky/demos/demo.html) in browsers that do not support position:sticky natively) and the corresponding [article](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit) to find out more. 
I would suggest using this technique as it works without any issues (even on mobile devices) and a robust [polyfill](https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-sticky) for older browser is already available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like Magellan from Foundation:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/magellan.html

If you want to do it by hand, you need to calculate the offset of each h1 by using [jQuery offset](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) and then binding to .scroll event a handler that displays and stickies the right element:

```
var $h1 = $("h1")

//Example: Offset top of the first h1
h1OffsetTop = $h1.eq(0).offset().top

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    //Do comparison to scrollTop to each h1, etc.
    //Then add fixed class to the correct h1 and remove it from all others
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Twitter Bootstrap Affix](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.1/js/affix.js) library which is a standalone implementation of exactly what you need. Just give it the data attributes you [need](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix-usage) like:

```
<section>

    <h1 data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="200">Title</h1>
    <div class="summary">
    ...
```

Alternatively you can compute the offset bottom if the content height is unknown:

```
$('h1').affix({
    offset: {
        top: 100
        , bottom: function () {
            return (this.bottom = $('.summary').offset().top + $('.summary').outerHeight(true))
        }
    }
})
```

Remember that the JavaScript implementation will be preferred over the data- attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little JavaScript / jQuery function based on [Stick div at top after scrolling](http://blog.yjl.im/2010/01/stick-div-at-top-after-scrolling.html) that should fit your needs:

```
function sticky()
{
    var window_top=$(window).scrollTop();
    var top_position=$('body').offset().top;
    var element_to_stick=$('h1');

    if (window_top > top_position) {
        element_to_stick.addClass('sticky').css('position', 'fixed');
    } else {
        element_to_stick.removeClass('sticky').css('position', 'relative');
    }
}
$(window).scroll(sticky);
sticky();
```

With the **sticky** CSS class you can make changes to the sticky element. Of course the **css('position', 'fixed|relative')** part can also be directly placed into the CSS.