# Replacing a title with position fixed, with another title position fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a node.js app using express and trying to do the following:

```
div(class="title")
  h1(class="h1_title") example_title
```

My jQuery for this is as follows:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function fixDiv() {
      var $cache = $('.title');
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 140)
        $cache.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '10px'});
      else
        $cache.css({'position': 'relative', 'top': 'auto'});
    }
    $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
    fixDiv();
});
```

So when I scroll the title will become fixed at the top of the page. Got this working, however! I have another title below this, the exact same code. But I'm trying to get my title to replace the previous one and become fixed.

So As your scrolling down through content, the title is always fixed but its just being updated with the title relevant to the content your viewing.

Can anyone help, I'd really appreciate it. I can't find anything which is what i'm exactly looking for and my knowledge is limited.
Thank you!

Comment: Mabe this question can help you [Fix title to top when section is visible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758599/fix-title-to-top-when-section-is-visible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you were asking a lot of questions about that ... I'm gonna show you an example that maybe can helps.

With an structure like this:

```
<div class="title">TITLE</div>
<div class="cont"><h1>TITLE</h1></div>
<div class="cont"><h1>Content1</h1></div>
<div class="cont"><h1>Content2</h1></div>
<div class="cont"><h1>Content3</h1></div>
```

Where `.title` gonna be the fixed header you can use Jquery to change the value base on the `h1` of the other containers.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $('.cont').each(function(){
    var t = $(this).offset().top - 50,
        tit = $(this).find('h1').text(),
        h = $(this).height(),
        ws = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (t < ws && ws < (h+t)) {
         $('.title').html(tit);
    } 
  })
})
```

Check this **[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJbExW)**

Comment: I apologise for not marking your answer correct sooner. I came across a work around where I didn't need to achieve what I wanted in the question I asked. However, I appreciate the time you spent answering and the demo which we're very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/jgxevwa6/1/ -- I didn't try to get the spacing perfect or anything.

You have your fixed class:

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

And then the magic. Basically any time you scroll, it cycles through each block and determines which is in the viewport by using a basic scrolling model:

```
(function($) { 
    var utils = {
        fixTitle: function(e) {
            var top = e.currentTarget.scrollY;

            $('div').each(function() {
                var thistop = $(this).position().top;
                if(top > thistop) {
                    $('.title').removeClass('fixed');
                    $(this).find('.title').addClass('fixed');
                }
            });
        }
    };

    $(function() {
        $(window).scroll(utils.fixTitle);    
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The javascript and CSS could be a little more accurate, but this gives you the basic gist of it.